# UpdatePanel does not work in a web application

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have the following simple code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Refresh"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="<%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in the master page there is a ToolkitScriptManager. but the update panel does not work never similar to they do not exist.

Note: I use .Net 4.0.

**Edit:** I removed the ToolKitScriptManager and added ScriptManager and the problem still exists. Seems the Ajax functionality is disabled in my application but I do not know how.

Any help!

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors?

Comment: @ vs dev: No, no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew the problem.

`<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Refresh"></asp:LinkButton>` must have an ID to do a partial postback to its Update Panel.

Answer (score 0):

can you post Code behind Code? I think you missed the databind method in code behind.
Are you getting any errors?